# Prolog: nat(s(s(0))) to "normal" decimal numbers

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

If an integers is defined like this in Prolog:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
```

How do I convert such a number to a decimal number?

The input is for example:

> s(s(s(0)))

I probably should add that I am very new to Prolog.

EDIT:
I tried it this way:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).

convert(N, C) :-
    C is C + 1,
    nat(N),
    convert(N, C).
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: I added one of my attempts.

Comment: What I want is a "normal" numerical representation like 0, 1, 2, 3, ... in order to use it as an index or to be able to use compares.

Comment: Prolog is not C, **C = C +1** always fails in Prolog because of unification. You must use another name **C1 is C + 1** for example

Comment: Thanks, that was just a typo, I'll correct that.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954435/convert-peano-number-sn-to-integer-in-prolog

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two cases you need to cover:

1. the *base case* `0` that maps on `0`; and
2. the *recursive case* `s(X)` that makes use of the result for `X`.

The base case thus looks like:

```
convert(0, 0).
```

the recursive case thus looks like:

```
convert(S(X), N) :-
    convert(X, N1),
    ….
```

where `…` is thus a step you need to do to determine `N` given `N1`. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, I am just going to throw out this recursive definition of numbers in the entire code base since I can't properly calculate with it.

Comment: It would be possible to write enough functions to calculate with them - that's the whole point of this model for basic mathematics - but it would be neither convenient nor efficient.